# `gulp` command starts, but quits quickly

Tags: node.js, gulp

when I try to run using `gulp` command, it starts running, but quits after that. How can I make it work as a server?

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:javascript tester$ ls
bower.json      bower_components    gulpfile.js     lib         node_modules        package.json
admins-MacBook-Pro:javascript tester$ gulp
[14:37:21] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/cakeshop/cakeshop-client-js/src/main/javascript/gulpfile.js
[14:37:21] Starting 'compile-libs'...
[14:37:21] Starting 'compile-combined'...
[14:37:21] Finished 'compile-libs' after 253 ms
[14:37:24] Finished 'compile-combined' after 3.28 s
[14:37:24] Starting 'compile'...
[14:37:24] Finished 'compile' after 27 μs
[14:37:24] Starting 'default'...
[14:37:24] Finished 'default' after 4.86 μs
admins-MacBook-Pro:javascript tester$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just run `gulp`, the default task is run. According to your output, the default task for your gulpfile depends on the `compile-libs`, `compile-combined`, and `compile` tasks, so those are executed in order.

The available tasks are defined in the `gulpfile.js` and as such are subject to your particular projects. We cannot tell you whether there is a development server task included or not, and we cannot tell you what it is called either.

You can get a list of available gulp tasks using `gulp --tasks`. Maybe you can spot a task that starts a server for you; you can then start that using e.g. `gulp server`. If there is no such task, you will have to write your own, setting up your own server.